# Ajax .can't figure it out

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I just finished learning Ajax so I tried to make a simple project(a simple port scanner), it not working for me.
I have no idea what is the problem. It's just showing 'Scan started'.
please help me.
There is no problem inside the php file, only in this code(VVVV)

```
var ports = [80, 22, 443, 21, 8080, 25, 3306];
function loadData(url, port){

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "<br>" + xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","scan.php?url=" + url + "&port=" + port,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}

function scan () {
    // body...
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Scan Started";
    if(document.getElementById("url").innerHTML){
        var url = document.getElementById("url").innerHTML;
        for (var i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
            loadData(url, ports[i]);
        };
    }
}
</script>
<center>
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url"><br><button onclick="scan()">Scan</button>
    <br>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Thanks,
Mr. Frost

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to scan other domains than your own, and javascript has a same origin policy

Comment: @adeneo — You can see the URL being requested in the code. It isn't (obviously) a cross origin policy issue.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Look at your browser's JavaScript console. Do you see any errors? Look at your browser's Developer Tools Net tab. Do you see the HTTP requests you are expecting being made? Do you see the responses you are expecting being received?

Comment: I got a php script who is working. Any way the problem was that I needed to use .value and not .innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the value from an text input, use the `value` property, not the `innerHTML` property.

An input element is defined as being EMPTY, it can't have any child nodes, so `innerHTML` should always be an empty string.

Comment: It's working! Thank you, I learned new thing bcuz of that :)